# how to only select where date time is newest

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

so I have some columns that contains date, time like `2017-09-01 05:24:03.090`

and I want to only get all the columns from the present day like `2017-09-01`

I had been trying with

```
where item.DateTimeModified = CONVERT (date, GETDATE ());
```

but that didn't give me anything so how exactly do I do this

Comment: You also have to convert `DateTimeModified`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both datetime-values.

Otherwise the whole datetime-value of `ìtem.DateModified` is compared to the current date-value.

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, item.DateTimeModified) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
where CONVERT(NVARCHAR,item.DateTimeModified,105) = CONVERT (NVARCHAR, GETDATE (),105);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize the modified date first and then compare with the normalized current date. For normalization first convert date into float then use floor and then convert it into datetime.

```
where cast(floor(cast(item.DateTimeModified as float)) as smalldatetime) = cast(floor(cast(GETDATE () as float)) as smalldatetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:-

```
CAST(item.DateTimeModified AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) query would be:

```
declare @Today as Date = Cast( GetDate() as Date ), @Tomorrow as Date;
set @Tomorrow = DateAdd( day, 1, @Today );

... where item.DateTimeModified >= @Today and item.DateTimeModified < @Tomorrow ...
```